# How can I find a specific chest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I picked up a lot of stuff, mostly books, as I did side quests. I had dozens of books but couldn't buy a house yet so I left them in a chest after killing some bandits and, genius me, forgot to mark where. I really want to get that stuff back. Is there any way to find where they are so I don't have to comb every little inch?

Comment: Are you on console or PC?

Comment: Can you remember anything specific about where you were when you dropped them off?

Comment: @Timelord64, it was someplace on a mountain. It was night so I don't really remember much else. Oh and the chest was facing toward the mountain from the opposite side of the camp.

Comment: Based on this description could be near Whiterun, atop White River Watch, but honestly it's just too vague. Also IIRC "random" chests get reset afte a while, so even if you find the right chest you may not find the loot.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because you asking us to find a chest on a mountain in game that full of chests and mountains

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to see which chests contain items that were placed there by the player.

Comment: Theoretically, you could possibly run a script in the console to loop over every chest in the game and see which chests have items in them other than those found in the Creation Kit. Nobody's going to bother with that though.